# Would the Openmv m7 camera module be suitable for an iris recognition system?

Tags: camera, iris-recognition, openmv

I am looking for a suitable camera for my iris recognition system but the prices of some of the cameras are steep, i stumbled on the openmv m7 which seems promising but the max resolution is 640x480 8 bit greyscale. The camera needs to be 20cm from the user.Please help!

Comment: There is an openmv cam H7+ which does QHD, but only at about 1 fps while the OpenMV IDE is running.  Saccadic motion of the eye is pretty fast, so you won't be able to catch that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade#Vision). But saccadic motion is large so you could track the iris at low resolution and just take higher resolution images when needed. The distance from the user shouldn't matter as you could use any lens to fill the sensor with the detail you need.